# Localization : Apply a ugettext by iterating over a dictionary doesn't work

Tags: python, django, dictionary, localization

I'm trying to localize strings by declaring a dictionary of english strings

```
english_strings = {
                      "smtp_text":
                          {
                              "server": "SMTP Server",
                              "port":"SMTP Port",
                              "error_unreachable_port":"Host or Port not reachable"
                          }
                  }
```

and then iterating the dictionary to apply a ugettext(..) over each 'value'. However that does not work and the dictionary remains unchanged.

```
  from django.utils.translation import ugettext
  smtp = english_strings["smtp_text"]
  for key  in smtp.keys()  :
        smtp[key] = ugettext(smtp[key])
```

However, the below works

```
smtp["server"] = ugettext( smtp["server"] )
smtp["port"] = ugettext( smtp["port"] )
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: Let me understand... are you using django.utils.translation.ugettext?

Comment: Yes, let me update the question.

Comment: mmm... it sounds strange to me, I don't understand why you are defining your translation in that way and what you expect to happen (what do you mean by "it works" "it does not work"?)... anyway you should avoid changing a collection while you are iterating it, try to create a new empty dictionary and stores your computed data on it

Comment: "It does not work" as in the message file created does not have the strings on which I applied the utext(..)